# Xamarin Forms (iOS) - If you use FormattedText for label with LineBreakMode = TrailTruncation, it do not add ellipses

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Give a try to add a label and add a long text against the property **FormattedText** - and set the  `LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"`. You will find that it's not adding the expected ellipses. But if you use the "Text" property it works fine. I still need to stick to this FormattedText property as we are achieving some formatting through this. Is there any alternative way to address this linebreak issue with FormattedText -

**Example:** "I need to show for long sample text with ellipses like in this example..."

```
<Grid Padding=" 0,50,0,0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height ="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label" FormattedText ="testing this big text as a sample which needs to get truncated at any cost" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  `ellipses` will appear when the content of the **Label** beyond it's border . I set the UnderLine in **FormattedText**  and it works fine in my project .

```
NSMutableAttributedString str = new NSMutableAttributedString("I need to show for long sample text with ellipses like in this example...");

            
UIStringAttributes attributes = new UIStringAttributes() { UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Double,UnderlineColor=UIColor.Red, };

str.AddAttributes(attributes, new NSRange(0, str.Length - 1));

label.AttributedText = str;

label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
```

### Update

in Forms you could use Custom Renderer .

Add the following class in your iOS project

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using xxx.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Label),typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this effort- I am using Xamarin.Forms and I did the similar in Xaml. where the property is been set. It goes out beyond border without trailtruncation.

Comment: You could post the full code or share the sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Thanks much! I had placed my code in renderer but not sure why it was not accepting. control.AttributedText = attrString;
 control.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation; where attrString was formatted. And this line was inside a function called from the same event... anyways, keeping the LineBreakMode in the OnElementChange event fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221083/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-shanand-c).